# Controls not appearing in document outline

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

We have a problem where some of the controls are declared in the Designer.cs but cannot be seen neither on the form nor on the document outline , For example lets say there is a label called label1 , and its declared on the Designer like this :_

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

// 
// label1
// 
resources.ApplyResources(this.label1, "label1");
this.label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.helpProvider1.SetHelpKeyword(this.label1, resources.GetString("label1.HelpKeyword"));
this.helpProvider1.SetHelpNavigator(this.label1((System.Windows.Forms.HelpNavigator(resources.GetObject("label1.HelpNavigator"))));
this.helpProvider1.SetHelpString(this.label1, resources.GetString("label1.HelpString"));
this.label1.Name = "label1";
this.helpProvider1.SetShowHelp(this.label1, ((bool)(resources.GetObject("label1.ShowHelp"))));
```

And that's all , now when we open the form we cannot see this label , and we cannot also see it on document outline .

We are not sure what really caused this but we believe that these controls ( objects ) are not disposable so by time when we open the from on run time more than 100 times we are facing a memory leak and overflow .

So our question is there any way to detect these controls in all the solution ? or should we delete them manually from the Designers ? and what really caused this and how can we prevent it from happening again .

Thank you .

Comment: try assign `this.label1.Text = "A long text"` in the designer.cs and check if it shows up.

Comment: I don't see the code where you add label1 to form (or another control)...

Comment: That is the problem , the control is not added to anywhere , we dont remember how it was created ,and if it was deleted why the deceleration code is still on the designer .

I tried what you suggested but nothing happened .